# Disable Wheelcolliders slip (Non realistic)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently learning Unity. I have learnt and did many projects and started making a new one about cars. My goal is NOT to achieve realistic physics. I'm trying to have a 0 slip.

I have done all the steps about the wheelcolliders, velocity, rotation, and overall movement. Currently I'm struggling to disable the car slip.

I don't want the car to slip at all. I tried using transform and change the position, but that isn't the method that I want to use.

Using the following method, I'm doing the acceleration:

```
    private void doAccelerate() {

    currentSpeed = (int) (rb.velocity.magnitude * 3.6f);
    if (!hasBraked) {
        if (hasReachedMax) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y, maxVelocity);
        } else {
            if (currentSpeed < maxSpeed) {
                rearDriverW.motorTorque = m_verticalInput * motorForce * motorAccelerate;
                rearPassengerW.motorTorque = m_verticalInput * motorForce * motorAccelerate;
            } else if (currentSpeed > maxSpeed) {
                hasReachedMax = true;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

The following two pics provide the UI units for the `Rigidbody` and `WheelColliders`.

[This pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99MM5.jpg), and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73PCR.jpg).

I would some suggestions to apply 0 slip. I have tried playing with the value, yet I didn't reach the perfect values. Nevertheless, I didn't understand it correctly. That's why I didn't know.